# Getting a row of data with an aggregate function that might be null

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to retrieve information from my database which includes a min function that may or may not be null. What I've found is that if the min is null then the query won't return any data.

This is my current code:

```
select store.StoreID, store.StoreManager,
  min(salesnumbers.totalsales)
from Store  
INNER JOIN salesnumbers on store.StoreID = salesnumbers.StoreID 
where store.StoreID = 17
GROUP BY StoreID;
```

I have also tried:

```
select store.StoreID, store.StoreManager,
  min(IFNULL(salesnumbers.totalsales, "N/A")) 
from Store  
INNER JOIN salesnumbers on store.StoreID = salesnumbers.StoreID 
where store.StoreID = 17
GROUP BY StoreID;
```

Which gives me the same result. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a column from your group by, which will cause erroneous results. Also, use an *outer* join:

```
select
    store.StoreID,
    store.StoreManager,
    min(salesnumbers.totalsales) totalsales
from Store  
left join salesnumbers on store.StoreID = salesnumbers.StoreID 
where store.StoreID = 17
group by 1, 2
```

Note the more convenient use of column *numbers* rather than expression in the group by (much easier to code, read and see if you've missed one)

Comment: Thank you the left join works! Can you go into more detail about why I would need to group by the second column though? Thanks.

Comment: @pyy . . . In this case, it is reasonable to only use the `id`, because of something called "functional dependency"; hence, your use is consistent with the ANSI standard.  However, in general, MySQL allows columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by`, and that typically leads to coding errors.